# How to compute the dot product of two distributed RowMatrix in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, linear-algebra, distributed-computing, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-multiplication

Let **`Q`** be a distributed Row Matrix in Spark, I want to calculate the cross product of **`Q`** with its transpose **`Q'`**.

However although a Row Matrix does have a **`multiply()`** method, but it can only accept local Matrices as an argument.

Code illustration ( Scala ):

```
val phi = new RowMatrix(phiRDD)            // phiRDD is an instance of RDD[Vector]
val phiTranspose = transposeRowMatrix(phi) // transposeRowMatrix()
                                           // returns the transpose of a RowMatrix
val crossMat = ?                           // phi * phiTranspose
```

Note that I want to perform the dot product of **2** **Distributed RowMatrix** not a distributed one with a local one.

One solution is to use an `IndexedRowMatrix` as following:

```
val phi = new IndexedRowMatrix(phiRDD)  // phiRDD is an instance of RDD[IndexedRow]
val phiTranspose = transposeMatrix(phi) // transposeMatrix()
                                        // returns the transpose of a Matrix
val crossMat = phi.toBlockMatrix().multiply( phiTranspose.toBlockMatrix()
                                             ).toIndexedRowMatrix()
```

However, I want to use the Row Matrix-Methods such as **`tallSkinnyQR()`** and this means that I sholud transform `crossMat` to a RowMatrix, using `.toRowMatrix()` method:

```
val crossRowMat = crossMat.toRowMatrix()
```

and finally I can apply

```
crossRowMat.tallSkinnyQR()
```

but this process includes many transformations between the types of the Distributed Matrices and according to what I understood from [MLlib Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html) this is expensive:

> It is very important to choose the right format to store large and distributed matrices. Converting a distributed matrix to a different format may require a global shuffle, which is quite expensive.

Would someone elaborate, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only distributed matrices which support matrix - matrix multiplication are `BlockMatrices`. You have to convert your data accordingly - artificial indices are good enough:

```
new IndexedRowMatrix(
  rowMatrix.rows.zipWithIndex.map(x => IndexedRow(x._2,  x._1))
).toBlockMatrix match { case m => m.multiply(m.transpose) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the algorithm listed on this [page](https://www.thinkbiganalytics.com/2015/11/23/scalable-matrix-multiplication-using-spark-2/) which moves the multiplication problem from dot product to distributed scalar product problem by using vectors outer product:

> The outer product between two vectors is the scalar product of the
>   second vector with all the elements in the first vector, resulting in
>   a matrix

My own created multiplication function (can be more optimized) for Row Matrices ended up like that.

```
def multiplyRowMatrices(m1: RowMatrix, m2: RowMatrix)(implicit ctx: SparkSession): RowMatrix = {

 // Zip m1 columns with m2 rows
val m1Cm2R = transposeRowMatrix(m1).rows.zip(m2.rows)

// Apply scalar product between each entry in m1 vector with m2 row
val scalar = m1Cm2R.map{
case(column:DenseVector,row:DenseVector) => column.toArray.map{
  columnValue => row.toArray.map{
    rowValue => columnValue*rowValue
  }
 }
}

// Add all the resulting matrices point wisely
val sum = scalar.reduce{
case(matrix1,matrix2) => matrix1.zip(matrix2).map{
  case(array1,array2)=> array1.zip(array2).map{
    case(value1,value2)=> value1+value2
  }
 }
}

new RowMatrix(ctx.sparkContext.parallelize(sum.map(array=> Vectors.dense(array))))
}
```

After that I tested both approaches- My own function and using block matrix - using a 300*10 Matrix on a one machine

Using my own function:

```
val PhiMat = new RowMatrix(phi)
val TphiMat = transposeRowMatrix(PhiMat)
val product = multiplyRowMatrices(PhiMat,TphiMat)
```

Using matrix transformation:

```
val MatRow = new RowMatrix(phi)
val MatBlock = new IndexedRowMatrix(MatRow.rows.zipWithIndex.map(x => IndexedRow(x._2,  x._1))).toBlockMatrix()
val TMatBlock = MatBlock.transpose
val productMatBlock = MatBlock.multiply(TMatBlock)
val productMatRow = productMatBlock.toIndexedRowMatrix().toRowMatrix()
```

The first approach spanned **1 job** with **5 stages** and took **2s** to finish in total. While the second approach spanned **4 jobs**, **three with one stage** and **one with two stages**, and took **0.323s** in total. Also the second approach outperformed the first with respect to the Shuffle Read/Write size.

Yet I am still confused by the [MLlib Programming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html) Guide statement:

> It is very important to choose the right format to store large and
>   distributed matrices. Converting a distributed matrix to a different
>   format may require a global shuffle, which is quite expensive.